# Silverlight: How to force binding after setting the DataContext property

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, data-binding

Is it possible to set the DataContext property of a usercontrol after the user control has been loaded, and force the usercontrol to rebind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that if you just set the datacontext again, it will rebind

Comment: If you are setting the data context to the same as what it was before it will not re-bind. In this case set it to null first, then to the what it was before, to force it to re-bind.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do extra work when the DataContext changes you can use a custom DependencyProperty and bind it to the DataContext property. Use the DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler to know when the DP changed.

For a more complete explanation see my blog post at http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/12/29/how-to-know-when-the-datacontext-changed-in-your-control.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the DataContext property should cause the rebind.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to force re-binding, for example:

```
MyDataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, 
    MyDataGrid.GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty).ParentBinding);
```

This method could be used for DataContext as well.