# easiest way to renew Datacontext binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

What is the fastest way to update my DataContext binding to my WPF usercontrol so that it shows changes in the object it is bound to in the view?

Comment: You asked two questions--what is easiest and what is fastest.  If you mean easiest to implement, OC<T> is it.

Answer (score 4):

The best option is to make your DataContext object implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).  Make any collections implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) (ie: use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`, etc).

If you do this, then the bindings will automatically stay up to date, with no effort on your part.

Comment: when the data in my datacontext changes, it doesn't show in my view, however I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.  I am using PRISM.

Comment: Which data in your DataContext?  If you're using collections, they must implement INot.CollectionChanged instead of propchanged.  Otherwise, this should work, as it's the "standard" way of working in WPF.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, didn't know about ObservableCollection<T> at all.

Answer (score 1):

Binding an ObservableCollection (which implements a specific interface) with objects that implement INotifyPropertyChanged will immediately show changes to their values in the front end or backend whenever you make changes, as long as the binding modes are set to two way binding.

Answer (score 0):

This question here appears to be very similar.

[Silverlight: How to force binding after setting the DataContext property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369873/silverlight-how-to-force-binding-after-setting-the-datacontext-property/369989#369989)

If you don't want to implement the INotifyProperty, you can use my answer and just set the datacontext again